# OpenCV enhancing colour image to make text stand out

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, ocr

I'm new to computer vision, what I'm trying to do is use OpenCV v4.5.x to take an image with any color ( except black ) background that has slightly blurry white text on it to read using an OCR program.

I want to maximize contrast/remove blurriness of the text and also change the background colour to black.

If I can get this to work, it will be hugely useful.

Thank you.

This is a sample image ( below )
The white vertical line between the "PSSU" and "356750" is a steel bar that just happens to be a white color. Probably need to work out how to work around it.

[image]

Comment: Show sample images

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is to use the `cv2.threshold` function.

An example of this working with you're example image is:

```
import cv2
    
image = cv2.imread("NPONW.png")
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(image,150,255,0)
cv2.imshow("test", thresh)
while True:
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
        break
    
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This will display the image on your screen in a window until you press "q" button

You can play with the second argument to improve the edges of the letters.

Comment: fundamental programming: move stuff out of the loop that isn't changing during the iteration

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, OP states in question "I want to maximize contrast/remove blurriness of the text and also change the background colour to black." Output from code does exactly that. As for the note... thanks for the tip, didn't catch that.